# When to use ridge estimator / naive Bayes

Tags: logistic, classification, naive-bayes, ridge-regression, weka

I used the Logistic function in weka, to predict a binary class. I have used SimpleLogistic before, but Logistic also seem to give me good results. I did want to clarify if I understand some things well on this classifier, pecially about the ridge estimator

Logistic does multinomial logistic regression with a ridge estimator.

- multinomial means for more then binary classes as well. So it would appear I didn't really need this function
- ridge estimator: I have been reading about this, but it is hard to summarise in one sentence. When attributes are highly correlated this might seem a good technique because XXt becomes close the zero otherwise. Is this correct? Do you have a better explanation in a few sentences?
- If my interpretation of ridge is correct. It seems to be valid in exactly the opposite case as when you should use Naive Bayes, because this assumes independent variables.

Thanks for validating and providing a short explanation of ridge (which I don't fully get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ridge is a regularization technique. In simple words, adding ridge to Logistic Regression means that you want to make a model that is not overfitting with the training data and hopefully generalizes well in the test data. It is done by adding penalty on weights learned. This way, the learner will try to find the weights that are close to zero and not the weights that try to fit every training points.

Binomial is a special case of Multinomial distribution (when N=2). So, your multinomial logistic regression can also handle the binary case well.